# How to evaluate string to object(values are functions) in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

How to evaluate following JavaScript string into JavaScript object.

```
var str = "{ key : function() {} }";
```

`eval(str)` returns error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ("

Comment: `eva('(' + str + ')')`

Comment: Please use the search before you ask a new question.